# intelHAXM is not installing even after enabling INTEL VT in BIOS

Tags: android, android-studio, bios, haxm

Emulator is not working in Android studio so i moved to install intelhaxa but its not setting and i followed many ways like:

```
                   1) cold boot
                   2) enabling the intel VT in BIOS
                   3) disabling the HYPER-V
                   4) disabling the avast antivirus
                   5) verified with the intel process identification.
```

but still its not installing, i tried many but not getting where is the fault,
 please suggest how to install the intelhaxm to run the emulators.

my system configurations:
 1) intel core i3 processor
 2) 2GB RAM
 3) windows 8.1 pro

Comment: So the problem is in installation or in booting of emulator ? If this is installation then mention the error you got.

Comment: problem with the installation  error: turn on the intel-vt

Comment: Have you enabled virtualization in bios setup ? please check it carefully .Also remmember that you have to set your emulator's ram below 1 GB otherwise you will see a boot loop.

Comment: Thank you so much, its working by uninstalling avast.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things you don't mention
Use the installer from https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager, not the one from Android Studio 
set xd bit (bcdedit /set nx AlwaysOn) 
run sfc /scannow  and reboot

Comment: i am using sony vaio(vpceh25en) i am not finding the xd to set in BIOS. what to do?